# Why is the below code printing more than 6 elements?

Tags: arrays, c, insert

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    int num, pos;
    printf("Enter the number to insert in the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Enter the position to enter the element in the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    if (pos < 0 || pos > size) {
        printf("Invalid position!");
    } else {
        // Move elements to make space for the new element
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= pos; i--) {
            a[i + 1] = a[i];
        }

        // Insert the new element
        a[pos] = num;

        // Update the size of the array
        size++;

        printf("The updated array is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code gives more than 6 elements in the array. The first 6 elements are printed correctly but the rest are random garbage value . What is the reason for that ?

Comment: The question to me is why do you even attempt to print 6? The `a` does not allow to access `a[6]` and yet you clearly intentionally do so (by this `size++;`, in case you do indeed ask about why more than 5....).

Comment: "`// Update the size of the array`", umm - you can't.

Comment: I doubt "The output of the code gives more than 6 elements in the array." and I don't get what you mean by "correctly" in "The first 6 elements are printed correctly ". Because  in `int a[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};` I count 5, not six. Please double check that your [mre] matches your question.

Comment: Your code is invoking undefined behaviour, so any result is valid — crashes, garbage output, what you expected; any of those is a valid possible result.

Comment: If you are indeed asking why it is printing more than 6, then the direct answer is most likely "Because the variable `size` is higher than 6 in the output loop." and the implicit answer is "Because of undefined behaviour." though undefined behaviour could also output 10 with size being 3. So, please, as a debug experiment, output the value of `size` before and after the output loop. That will help to understand a possible way of undefined behaviour - without really explaining how/why, because of, by definition of undefined behaviour, you can't.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the issue and prevent printing garbage values, you need to declare a new array with a size one element larger than the original array, and then perform the insertion. Here's a modified version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    int num, pos;

    printf("Enter the number to insert in the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Enter the position to enter the element in the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    if (pos < 0 || pos > size)
    {
        printf("Invalid position!");
    }
    else
    {
        // Create a new array with one extra element
        int updated_size = size + 1;
        int updated_array[updated_size];

        // Copy elements before the specified position
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        {
            updated_array[i] = a[i];
        }

        // Insert the new element
        updated_array[pos] = num;

        // Copy elements after the specified position
        for (int i = pos; i < size; i++)
        {
            updated_array[i + 1] = a[i];
        }

        // Print the updated array
        printf("The updated array is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < updated_size; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", updated_array[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right. However, I suspect that a new larger array, which is only available within the `else{...}` will not get OP much further with whatever they are trying (or will be trying on the next step of their journey).

Answer (score 2):

When we create an array like:

`int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};`
It allocates `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` blocks of memory.

So when you do `size++`, it is **logically incorrect**.

The array is *static* and its **size cant be modified**.

If you wish to have a dynamic array, use `malloc()` or `calloc()`
These functions allocate memory in the heap. And if you wish to increase (or decrease) the size of array, you can do that by invoking the function `realloc()`.
Remember: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()` belong to the `stdlib.h` header file.

And also, when you are allocating memory in the *heap*, remember to *de-allocate* OR `free()` the memory, otherwise it may result in **memory leak**.

Comment: Implementing a linked list would also allow adding of values dynamically.

Comment: Yes but that would require additonal coding (implementing a linked list).

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
int a[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

Defines an array of five `int`s. The valid indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.

This line correctly calculates the size as 5.

```
int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
```

This fragment

```
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= pos; i--) {
            a[i + 1] = a[i];
        }
```

shifts all the numbers in the array from `pos` to the top up one slot. This is where the first problem is. If `pos == size` nothing happens, but, if `pos < size`, the first thing that happens is that the item in `a[size-1]` is copied to `a[size]`. The trouble is that `size` is 5 and the indexes are 0 ... 4 inclusive. `a[size]` is *not in the array*. This is known as a "buffer overrun". `a` is a buffer and you've written a value outside of it. It is an example of what the C standard calls undefined behaviour. That means anything can happen.

What actually happens next depends on the compiler implementation and the underlying machine architecture. If you are lucky, the memory locations after the array are not being used for anything and your print at the end will *appear* to work correctly, even though your program is broken. If you are unlucky, the location after the array is being used for something important and unpredictable behaviour may ensue.

Judging from the symptoms you describe (more than 6 elements being printed), I would say that the compiler is storing the variable `size` immediately after the end of the array. Thus the first copy from `a[size-1]` will clobber it, **or**, if you enter `5` for `pos`, `size` will be overwritten by `num`. Either way it's bad news for the `for` loop that does the printing.

You have two choices to fix this depending on your ultimate goal. If this is just an exercise and you only ever intend to do one insertion, make the array of size 6 by adding a dummy valuer at the end of the initialiser and adjust `size` to account for it

```
    int a[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 0};
    //                             ^--- Dummy value
    int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) - 1;
    //                                  ^^^- reduces size from 6 to 5
```

If, ultimately you want to be able to repeat the insertion an arbitrary number of times, you'll need to allocate the array dynamically using `malloc()` and resize it before each insertion using `realloc()`.

Answer (score -1):

The reason the code is printing more than 6 elements is that it is accessing and printing uninitialized elements of the array. The array a is declared with a size of 5 elements:

```
int a[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

Then, after inserting an element into the array, the size of the array is updated:

```
size++;
```

However, the size of the array a does not actually change. In C, arrays have a fixed size once they are declared. The variable size only keeps track of the number of elements you are using for insertion purposes, but it doesn't resize the array itself.

So, when you loop to print the array using the updated size, the loop goes beyond the actual initialized elements in the array and accesses garbage values from memory.

To fix this issue, you should only print the elements up to the valid size of the array, which is stored in the variable size. Modify your print loop like this:

```
printf("The updated array is: ");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
  printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

This way, you will only print the valid elements in the array up to the position where you inserted the new element.

Comment: I do not think that you are answering the question why it is printing more than 6.